# AJAX Modal Form

Tags: ajax, modal-dialogs

I created a modal form with Ajax:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Drupal\hello\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;


/**
 * Description of HelloModalForm
 *
 * @author arthur
 */
class HelloModalForm extends FormBase {
  
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $form['node_title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Node\'s title'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Enter a portion of the title to search for'),
    );
    
    $form['actions']['type'] = 'actions';
    
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Search'),
      '#ajax' => array( // here we add ajax callback where we will process
        'callback' => '::open_modal', // the data that came from the form in modal window
       ),
    );
    
    $form['#title'] = 'Seach for Node by Title';
    
    return $form;
     
  }
  
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'hello_model_form';
  }
  
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // input your code for validation, no validation required in this search
  }
  
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    
  }
  
  public function open_modal(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $node_title = $form_state->getValue('node_title');
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('title', $node_title, 'CONTAINS');
    $entity = $query->execute();
    $key = array_keys($entity);
    $id = !empty($key[0]) ? $key[0] : NULL;
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $title = 'Node ID';
    if ($id !== NULL) {
      $content = '<div class="test-popup-content"> Node ID is: ' . $id . '</div>';
      $options = array(
        'dialogClass' => 'popup-dialog-class',
        'width' => '300',
        'height' => '300',    
      );
      $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));
    } else {
      $content = 'Not found record with this title <strong>' . $node_title . '</strong>';
      $options = array(
        'dialogClass' => 'popup-dialog-class',
        'width' => '300',
        'height' => '300',
      );
      $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));
    }
    return $response; 
  }
}
```

Error Message on calling Modal form:

> User error: "type" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
> Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children(Array) (Line: 1027)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm('hello_model_form', Array, Object) (Line: 1073)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm('hello_model_form', Array, Object) (Line: 575)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('hello_model_form', Array, Object) (Line: 321)
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 91)
> Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 573)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 151)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
> User error: "type" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
> Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children(Array, ) (Line: 402)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}() (Line: 573)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
> call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Comment: Did you check that the value of `$node_title` is indeed a string not an array?

Comment: Here's definition of 'note_title'  $form['node_title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Node\'s title'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Enter a portion of the title to search for'),
    );

Comment: Reproduced the ModalForm code

Answer (score 0):

> User error: "type" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children()

You forgot the leading `#` in your `actions` form render element:

```
$form['actions']['type'] = 'actions';
```

Should be:

```
$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
                  ^ Add leading #.
```

Comment: Great, you save my day.